# ¿Por qué en el informe de KEYWORD_PERFORMANCE_REPORT no obtengo el CriteriaDestinationUrl?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, adword

Cuando realizo mi script de google adwords de KEYWORD_PERFORMANCE_REPORT y quiero obtener la variable CriteriaDestinationUrl en el google sheet están los campos vacíos, he probado con otros reportes y sucede exactamente lo mismo no entiendo el porque el campo esta vacío.

¿Alguien puede ayudarme?

```
function main() {
var spreadsheeturl = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DNqIjieI-  l9rCu4cKQ9lVU0NFH2nLg3ogznFdynb6Qo/edit#gid=0';
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(spreadsheeturl);
var active = sheet.getActiveSheet();
var report = AdWordsApp.report("SELECT   Date,CampaignName,AdGroupName,CriteriaDestinationUrl, Criteria FROM KEYWORDS_PERFORMANCE_REPORT WHERE Conversions > 0 DURING LAST_7_DAYS");
report.exportToSheet(active);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El campo está vacío porque AdwordsApp no está ni en los servicios incluidos ni en los servicios avanzados de Google Apps Script.

Es posible que puedas acceder AdworsdsApp conectándolo como una API externa. Los detalles en https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external

## Referencias

### Documentación

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/

### Preguntas similares en Stack Overflow en inglés

- [Use Adwords API (MccApp) in Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28030902/use-adwords-api-mccapp-in-google-apps-script)

Comment: Gracias, Ruben, como no podía encontrar la solución para obtener el criterialurl, lo hice de otra manera y con otro informe y php.